# TypeError: float argument required, not str

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to solve a linear integer with programming and have encountered a problem called `TypeError: float argument required, not str`.

This is my current code:

```
from pulp import * 
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('y', (M, C, W), None, pulp.LpInteger)
prob += pulp.lpSum(cost[m][c][w]*y[m][c][w] for m in M for c in C for w in W)
for i in M:
for j in C:
prob += pulp.lpSum(y[i][j][k] for k in W)==x[j][i]
prob.writeLP('Resource_Dispatch.lp')
```

Comment: Please add more detail about the exception to your question.

Comment: you have to fix your indentation before anyone can help.  also that's a lot of nested list comprehensions yo

Answer (score 1):

From:

```
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('y', (M, C, W), None, pulp.LpInteger)
```

To:

```
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('y', (M, C, W), None, None, pulp.LpInteger)
```

What's wrong with the first line is that the lowerbound is `None` while upperbound is `pulp.LpInteger`